# Установить node.js на готовый сайт

Tags: node.js

Добрый день! Есть уже работающий интернет магазин. Есть рут доступ isp manager,а также не настроенный root SSH(И так будет еще долго).
Хочу к нему подключить node.js, а к нему gulp с cron'ом, дабы сжать тысячи уже залитых изображений.Раньше ни разу этого не делал, сейчас только скачал и разархивировал его на сервере(через wget ) На команду node -v ругается, пишет, что такой не знает.

Comment: Я не уверен, но вероятнее всего через `ips manager` это сделать нельзя, нужно делать через `SSH`

Comment: А задача какая стоит? Для чего это все?

Answer (score 1):

Скорее всего у тебя ничего не получиться. У меня была когда то такая проблема, я заливал на хост nodejs распаковывал, с помощью нода запускал сервер. Но он можно сказать будет работать только локально, к нему подключиться никак нельзя. Советую тестовый дешевый впс тебе взять. Там все нормально работать будет.

Comment: я пользовался firstvds, найдешь дешевле - поделись)